# How to use Python type annotations with a set of related, auto-generated modules that must be used dynamically in a client?

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

I have a set of auto-generated modules, which I generate with [datamodel-code-generator](https://github.com/koxudaxi/datamodel-code-generator/). I have a set because I have to hit different API endpoints in different scenarios, but the underlying data model for those API's is identical or close to identical. Assume that I define each of these data models in their own auto-generated module:

moduleA.py:

```
# Auto-generated
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Bar(BaseModel):
    y: str
    x: bool # <- Only present in moduleA


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: str
    c: float # <- Only present in moduleA
    sub: Bar
```

moduleB.py:

```
# Auto-generated
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Bar(BaseModel):
    y: str
    z: int # <- Only present in moduleB


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: str
    sub: Bar
```

Then, in a client class I would like to use these different modules dynamically as such:

```
import moduleA, moduleB

class Client:
    def __init__(self, flag: bool):
        if flag:
            dm = moduleA
        else:
            dm = moduleB
        obj = dm.Foo(x="hello", sub=dm.Bar(y="world", z=1, x=False))
        print(obj, type(obj))
client = Client(flag=True)
```

This will work, but pyright in strict mode will complain that `Argument of type "Bar" cannot be assigned to parameter "sub" of type "Bar" in function "__init__". Type "Bar" cannot be assigned to type "Bar" "moduleB.Bar" is incompatible with "moduleA.Bar"`

What is the correct way of creating type annotations for this type of structure? Possible avenues for a solution could e.g. be to

- use [Protocols](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) somehow?
- create and maintain a [Facade](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/facade)?

Answer (score 0):

On solution would be to create a [Facade](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/facade). This can be handled by creating a `facade.py` module. This will allow us to define facade classes which have to declare mappings to the concrete moduleA and moduleB classes. I use Pydantic's to_dict() method for this mapping, but can override it on a class by class basis.

facade.py

```
from types import ModuleType
from typing import Optional, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, main

import moduleA, moduleB

class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]


class FacadeConfig(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    _DATA_MODEL: ModuleType

    def set_data_model(self, dm: ModuleType):
        self._DATA_MODEL = dm

    def get_data_model(self):
        return self._DATA_MODEL

facade_config = FacadeConfig()

class Facade(BaseModel):
    def to_dm(self):
        return getattr(facade_config.get_data_model(), type(self).__name__)(
            **self.dict()
        )

class Bar(Facade):
    y: str
    z: int # <- Only present in B
    x: bool # <- Only present in A

    # It is possible to override how an object is reflected to the underlying models and make the behaviour depend on the concrete class
    def dict(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        if facade_config.get_data_model() == moduleA:
            return {"y": self.y + "!", "x": self.x}
        else:
            return {"y": self.y + "?", "z": self.z}

class Foo(Facade):
    x: str
    c: float = 0.0 # <- Only present in A and not desired to set manually
    sub: Bar
```

Now the client can be defined as:

```
import facade

class Client:
    def __init__(self, flag: bool):
        if flag:
            facade.facade_config.set_data_model(moduleA)
        else:
            facade.facade_config.set_data_model(moduleB)

        obj = facade.Foo(x="hello", sub=facade.Bar(y="world", z=1, x=False)).to_dm()
        print(obj, type(obj))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client1 = Client(flag=False)
    client2 = Client(flag=True)
```